# How to uninstall all trackers (tracker-miner: fs, apps)

Tags: cpu-load, software-uninstall, administration, tracker

How can I uninstall this programs in Ubuntu 16.04? Permanently from being installed by updates.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I solved by uninstalling [Tracker-Extract](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker):

```
sudo apt purge tracker-extract
```

This purges `tracker-extract* tracker-miner-fs*` and deletes data.

Comment: probably not a good idea as it also kills your machine ... here is what I see when running your command `The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons* nautilus* nautilus-share* tracker-extract* tracker-miner-fs* ubuntu-desktop* ubuntu-desktop-minimal*`

Comment: @ScottStensland For me this CPU hog was removable without removing entire @-desktop, though I am on Lubuntu.