# Is downloading a pdf from google drive resource intensive? (firefox)

Tags: firefox, crash, malware

I tried downloading three pdfs via google drive through firefox.
All of a sudden, my laptop - lenovo ideapad 330s heated up while the pdfs havent finished downloading at all.
 I downloaded `htop` to see what was happening. 
All I saw that was suspicious was `libexec tracker-miner-fs` and `lib-exec-document-portal` running as user - me. I didn't get any idea... finally decided to close firefox without waiting for the download to complete as they are taking such a long time for a 20 mb file. I saw that all three were partially downloaded missing a few hundred pages.
 I deleted the partially downloaded file via the `GUI` by clicking the `delete button`. 
The laptop was still overheated.
 I looked up at `top` and saw that I was running a `Priv cont` process.
 As I understand, It is used to run processes as higher Privileged? I `kill` the process with its `PID` and reboot the laptop.
 I don't know If I am paranoid or something. Can someone make any sense out of this? after the reboot, the heating subsided.

I also looked at the `auth.log` located at `~/var/log/auth.log` - its output

I cant help but notice that `pam_unix` is trying to access  `/etc/securetty` which is a really badly named `dir`. The dir didnt exist in my local storage and thus returned an error as seen in the log.

The pdfs had an average size of 20 mb and the average number of pages were 500.

Or is it a bug with firefox? As I understand through other posts, the print in firefox isnt working well. and I used the print to pdf in firefox to download my files.

It is Ubuntu 20.04 - Focal fossa.

Comment: securetty is correctly named - secure and tty concatenated and I have no problems printing from FF in v20.04

Comment: There's almost no information in your rant. Is this on Ubuntu? Which release? How is it connected? What's your MTU?

Comment: @waltinator thanks for pointing that out. I edited the post.

Comment: @24601 thanks for the comment. So, pam_unix is cleared then. mustve been a bug with firefox? And my MTU is  1492 - taken from [link](letmecheck.it/mtu-test.php)

Comment: It could have been a Firefox bug. It could have been a Tracker bug. It could have been a networking problem. It could have been a cosmic ray. It could have been a lot of things. Voting to close - you don't seem to have any way for a Bug Triager or Developer to reliably reproduce the issue so they can trace down the actual cause. If you do discover a way to reliably reproduce the behavior, please file a bug report. The developers would love to fix it.

Comment: I have seen some people complaining about `tracker-miner-fs` eating up all their processor resources. Maybe the filesystem change with the progressing download sent tracker miner fs crazy. Which I would readily believe, since it already has a very unfortunately chosen name, doesn't it.

Comment: Additionally, while I don't remember experiencing anything specific around downloading pdfs with Firefox, I indeed experienced some interesting activities kicking in right while interacting with Firefox (and usually never with any other program). I have seen `jbd2` to go full gung-ho on my disk a few times while Firefoxing, and also some onslaught of `apparmor` audits with `profile_replace` operation... I don't know what these mean because I'm an amateur.

Comment: @user535733 Yes I don't seem to have  any way to triage the bug because as you can see above, I am an amateur. Maybe its the cosmic rays. Cause I don't think of anything else that could push my laptop into a deadlock just for downloading 20 mb pdf files. I have accepted an answer. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *tracker-miner-fs* is a background process that indexes documents on the off-chance that you might want to use a full text search on them some day.

I personally resent the very thought of that, and I believe that Linux desktop development has taken a wrong turn when they introduced that kind of thing: When I want to do a full text search in a lot of documents, I am prepared to wait for a moment, even a minute or two. But I am not prepared to let my system get bogged down every time I handle documents, such as you did: Downloading a lot of them.

I try my best to keep my system clean of such software, but that is getting increasingly harder as pretty much all desktops come with something like that preinstalled, and it's not that easy to get rid of them.

See also here:

- [How to uninstall all trackers (tracker-miner: fs, apps)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876304/how-to-uninstall-all-trackers-tracker-miner-fs-apps)
- https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-completely-disable-tracker.html
- [tracker-store and tracker-miner-fs eating up my CPU on every startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346211/tracker-store-and-tracker-miner-fs-eating-up-my-cpu-on-every-startup)

Comment: Do you know how can I even access, or rather, benefit from the index gained this way? If I search in Nautilus, it will show only matches in directory- and file names, but not in their content...

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer cuz I don't think its anything else. I have a simple ubuntu desktop environement - clutter less. Nothing running in the background except maybe pre-loader daemon that I installed manually.